# Can I authenticate with AWS Cognito from plain Java?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want to test custom user authorization with Cognito and do it from a simple java code. The problem is, the CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider requires an Android ApplicationContext and won't accept a null.

The whole flow is supposed to go like this:

1. User logs in using an email and password
2. Backend (a Lambda function) gets an IdentityToken from Cognito and returns it to the user
3. User can now retrieve credentials from Cognito and initialize an ApiClientFactory to authorize calls to other API endpoints

Is there something I'm missing or do I just have the whole concept wrong? Any good tutorials on this? I've already went through every possible documentation on AWS but I find it really hard to wrap my head around it and there is not a single material on plain Java, only Android.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally Amazon Cognito is used from "untrusted" clients like mobile and JavaScript apps to vend temporary AWS Credentials directly to the end user. Since the most common Java client-side apps we see are Android apps, our guides focus on Android rather than plain Java, but the same process will work with the Java SDK.

#### Server Side

When using Amazon Cognito's [Developer Authenticated Identities feature](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/#connect-to-an-existing-social-identity) as you mentioned you are doing, you'll get an OpenID Connect token back from the call to Amazon Cognito's [GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity.html) on your backend (lambda) function. Your backend should provide that token to the client application after successfully authenticating the user.

#### Client Side

Then the client-side application needs to make a call to Cognito's [GetCredentialsForIdentity API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetCredentialsForIdentity.html) ([Java docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cognitoidentity/AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.html#getCredentialsForIdentity(com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest))) passing in the token from the Server Side step above to get AWS Session Credentials as a [Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/securitytoken/model/Credentials.html) object in the Java SDK. With these session credentials (which are effectively credentials from the AWS Security Token Service/STS), create a `BasicSessionCredentials` object, passing it the session credentials and session token as described under [*Explicitly Specifying Credentials*  in the Java SDK developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/credentials.html#credentials-explicit).

Comment: Thanks, this clears things up. I understand you aim for Android, I was lost at the Provider requiring ApplicationContext which I cannot provide in regular Java. I guess I was just lost in the documentation. With a fresh mind today I'll try your guidelines and come back with any results.

Comment: Ok, I'm able to retrieve the IdentityId and OpenID Token from the backend but as soon as I'm trying to use GetCredentialsForIdentity API I get rejected with "Please provide a valid public provider". I'm setting the identityId of the request to the identityId I received from backend and a Logins map where the key is my developer id and the value is the received token. I'm sure the developer id is correct.

Comment: Sigh, after fighting some more I have figured out that the Logins map should have a key of "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com" and value of the openid token. I had to google around for a long, long time, just to find this very string mentioned on some stack overflow post. Perhaps it should be more clearly highlighted in the documentation?

Comment: Glad you found it. I agree it could be better on this point.  This isn't obvious because with the mobile SDKs (iOS, Android, Unity, etc) actually do use the developer provider name. Since you are using Plain Java this is different. Where exactly in the documentation were looking for this information? The Cognito Developer Guide? The Java SDK reference?

Comment: Mainly here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/#connect-to-an-existing-social-identity    but also in the Java SDK, Android SDK and in the API references linked in your post. Having the credentials and creating a BasicSessionCredentials object I am now seeking how to authorize calls to API Gateway with it, as the ApiFactory seems to expect an implementation of AWSCredentialsProvider and the Java SDK doesn't seem to have classes that allow using API Gateway. Am I forced to do the requests (and the robust signing procedure) manually here?

Comment: This is driving me insane. I have the BasicSessionCredentials, but the ApiClientFactory (from Android SDK) expects an implementation of AWSCredentialsProvider. How do I make one having only the access key, secret key and session token in BasicSessionCredentials? I have also tried the aws-apigateway-sdk-java-1.1.0 (which I randomly found on maven repo because it's not mentioned anywhere on Api Gateway pages) but that also expects a Provider and I don't see the possibility of using my generated Api SDK with it. I know I'm bothering you here quite significantly, but this stuff is cryptic as hell.

Comment: Sorry you're encountering difficulty here. In your original post, I understood you were asking about *plain* Java so this is the AWS SDK for Java - which doesn't have built-in Cognito support - which his why we introduced the Java SDK's `BasicSessionCredentials`. However, for a client using an SDK generated by API Gateway, it assumes you're using the Android SDK...

Comment: ...If you can use the Android SDK, do so and then you can use the `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider` as described in the [the Developer Authenticated Identities topic in the Cognito Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/). If the Android SDK won't work for you I'll talk to the API Gateway guys and figure out the best way to call API Gateway APIs from plain Java.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications. I must say I find this odd - I have received the credentials and I have the BasicSessionCredentials object - why can't I simply use it to sign calls? Why the need to build a Provider? I mean, it's obviously useful to make a Provider in most cases, but it would also be nice to have a possibility of doing this manually, so to say - leveraging the SessionCredentials I have, without the need to construct a Provider. Get credentials -> sign requests -> done.

Comment: You can just use the credentials. Their is a readme.md in the generated SDK showing a few different ways you can use credentials. However, the Cognito credential provider does provide some added benefits like caching the identity id and automatically refreshing credentials when they expire. Are you using android to call API Gateway or plain Java?

Comment: I'm using plain Java for testing purposes for now but the target system is for iOS. I just wanted to get a hold of the process to explain it later to the iOS guys. Thanks for your help, I've managed to get an authorized call through. I just wanted to point out that the StaticCredentialsProvider is not mentioned anywhere in the Java SDK online doc and if it weren't for you mentioning the readme.md file I would have never known about its existence (unless I manually skimmed through the classes in the library in a final desperate attempt to make this work :) )

Comment: Glad you got it working. We're listening and will use your feedback to make things better!

Answer (score 0):

Try this link : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/use-amazon-cognito-in-your-website-for-simple-aws-authentication/

It explains everything for Java SDK. Similar to the reporter I had a harrowing experience going through loads of documentations before arriving here.

Comment: Please, avoid link-only answers. They become obsolete if the remote resource is not available. Try to describe the most important aspects of the solution in your post.